# Printing a 2dim array using toString and Formatting

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, tostring

How can I right-align a 2dim array when printing using toString?

Here is my toString method currently and it's output.

```
 public String toString(){
       String result = "";
       for(int r = 0; r < size; r++){
           for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
               result += " " + matrix[r][c];
           result += "\n";
       }
       return result;         
   }
```

The left side is my output, the right is right-aligned.

[image: Wrong]
[image: Right]

Comment: Isn't this `left-aligned` already? Can you show a sample output of what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I mean right-aligned. Fixed in question.

Comment: Use printf() to left align your array.
Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075899/left-aligning-with-printf-in-java

Comment: I want it formatted as a String.